# Next pages and scrapy crawler doesn't work

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to follow the pages on [this website](http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69) where the next page number generation is pretty strange. Instead of normal indexation, next pages look like this:

```
new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=2&pnum=3
new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=2&pnum=3&pnum=4
new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=2&pnum=3&pnum=4&pnum=5
```

and as a result my scraper gets into loop and never stops, scraping items from this kind of pages:

```
DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1&pnum=1&pnum=1&pnum=2&pnum=3>`
```

and so on.
While the scraped items are correct and match the target(s), crawler never stops, going for pages all over again.

my crawler looks like this:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import re
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin


from mymobile.items import MymobileItem


class MmobySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mmoby2" 
    allowed_domains = ["mymobile.ge"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1"
    ]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("new/v2.php\?cat=69&pnum=\d*", ))
            , callback="parse_items", follow=True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath('//table[@width="1000"]//td/table[@class="probg"]')
        items = []
        for t in titles:
            url = t.xpath('tr//a/@href').extract()
            item = MymobileItem()
            item["brand"] = t.xpath('tr[2]/td/text()').re('^([\w\-]+)')
            item["model"] = t.xpath('tr[2]/td/text()').re('\s+(.*)$')
            item["price"] = t.xpath('tr[3]/td//text()').re('^([0-9\.]+)')
            item["url"] = urljoin("http://mymobile.ge/new/", url[0])

            items.append(item)

        return(items)
```

any suggestion how can I tame it?

Comment: Sorry, fell asleep :). See the updated question with full code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it. All page numbers appear in your start url, `http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1`, so you could use `follow=False` and the rule only will be executed once but it will extract all the links in that first pass.

I tried with:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import re
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin


class MmobySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mmoby2" 
    allowed_domains = ["mymobile.ge"]
    start_urls = [ 
        "http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1"
    ]   

    rules = ( 
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(
                allow=("new/v2\.php\?cat=69&pnum=\d*",),
            )   
            , callback="parse_items", follow=False),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        print response.url
```

Ran it like:

```
scrapy crawl mmoby2
```

And the number of request count was six, with following output:

```
...
2014-05-18 12:20:35+0200 [mmoby2] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1> (referer: None)
2014-05-18 12:20:36+0200 [mmoby2] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1> (referer: http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1)
http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1
2014-05-18 12:20:37+0200 [mmoby2] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1&pnum=4> (referer: http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1)
http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1&pnum=4
2014-05-18 12:20:38+0200 [mmoby2] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1&pnum=2> (referer: http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1)
http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1&pnum=2
2014-05-18 12:20:38+0200 [mmoby2] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1&pnum=5> (referer: http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1)
http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1&pnum=5
2014-05-18 12:20:39+0200 [mmoby2] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1&pnum=3> (referer: http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1)
http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1&pnum=3
2014-05-18 12:20:39+0200 [mmoby2] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-05-18 12:20:39+0200 [mmoby2] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 1962,
         'downloader/request_count': 6,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
         ...
```

Answer (score 4):

If extracting links with Smgllinkextractor fails you can always use simple scrapy spider and extract links for next page with selectors/xpaths, then yield Request for next page with callback to parse and stop process when there is no next page link.

Something like this should work for you.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request

class MmobySpider(Spider):
    name = "mmoby2"
    allowed_domains = ["mymobile.ge"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=1"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath('//table[@width="1000"]//td/table[@class="probg"]')
        items = []
        for t in titles:
            url = t.xpath('tr//a/@href').extract()
            item = MymobileItem()
            item["brand"] = t.xpath('tr[2]/td/text()').re('^([\w\-]+)')
            item["model"] = t.xpath('tr[2]/td/text()').re('\s+(.*)$')
            item["price"] = t.xpath('tr[3]/td//text()').re('^([0-9\.]+)')
            item["url"] = urljoin("http://mymobile.ge/new/", url[0])

            yield item

        # extract next page link
        next_page_xpath = "//td[span]/following-sibling::td[1]/a[contains(@href, 'num')]/@href"
        next_page = sel.xpath(next_page_xpath).extract()

        # if there is next page yield Request for it
        if next_page:
            next_page = urljoin(response.url, next_page[0])
            yield Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Xpath for next page is not an easy one due to completely unsemantic markup of your page, but it should work ok.

Comment: Thanks mate for this wonderful hint. I have to look deeper into this.